# simple client server communication between java and php

Tags: java, php, sockets

I need to send information from php client to java server, but none is receiving on server side though one print statement is successfully executed on server, the text from client is not able to receive on the server side. Here are the codes:

Java Server:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class javaphp2 {
    private static ServerSocket socket;

    private static Socket connection;
    private static String command       = new String();
    private static String responseStr   = new String();

    private static int port = 4309;

    public static void main(String args[])  {
        System.out.println("Signal Server is running.");

        try  {
            socket = new ServerSocket(port);

            while (true)  {
                connection = socket.accept();

                InputStreamReader inputStream = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
                DataOutputStream response = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(inputStream);

                command = input.readLine();
                //System.out.println("The input is" + command);
                response.writeBytes(responseStr);
                response.flush();
                //response.close();

                System.out.println("Running");
            }
        } catch (IOException e)  {
            System.out.println("Fail!: " + e.toString());
        }

        System.out.println("Closing...");
    }
}
```

PHP Client:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -q
<?php
$address = '132.119.90.165';
$port = 4309;

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, getprotobyname('tcp'));
socket_connect($socket, $address, $port);

$message = 'Apple';
$len = strlen($message);

$status = socket_sendto($socket, $message, $len, 0, $address, $port);
if($status !== FALSE)
{
    $message = '';
    $next = '';
    while ($next = socket_read($socket, 4096))
    {
        $message .= $next;
    }

    echo $message;
}
else
{
    echo "Failed";
}

socket_close($socket);
?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it !,

We need to add `$message = "Apple\n";` instead of `$message = 'Apple\n';`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a line-end to your message.

```
$message = 'Apple\n';
```

readLine will always wait for the line-end.