# I want to run a java class from a php script and return the result back to the php page

Tags: java, php

I have a simple Hello World java program written in Netbeans 6.7.1
Here it is:

```
package javaapplication2;

public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }

}
```

I want to create a php file which executes this code on the click of a button, and returns the output to the php page.

Can someone please post the exact php code and also tell me where to make any changes in any settings for this to run.

Settings could be any regarding the netbeans configurations or anything. But the code should work. Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17375308/how-to-run-java-code-class-using-php-and-display-on-the-same-web-page

Comment: https://phpcoderblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/31/php-java-run-java-from-php-tutorial-how-to-run-java-code-from-php-use-java-in-php-java-php-php-to-java-tutorial/

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please take a moment to take a look at the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to write a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using 2 differents technologies, you should make a connection between them through a service or a socket connection. It is not as simple as make a button.

Please see this example posted here in stackoverflow about a socket connection, and google a little more about "php and java connection":

[simple client server communication between java and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118371/simple-client-server-communication-between-java-and-php)

Regards.

Comment: i am not able to make a connection, neither i am able to call the java class from php script.